# Macbook Pro M1 shows cross in battery icon

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, apple-silicon, power-management

Since yesterday, my mac is showing a cross in battery icon in menu bar.

[image: Battery icon in menu bar]

I'm unable to boot it up after shutting down without plugging in the charger. On removing charger, battery in system preferences shows battery health as normal and current charge as 1% but I'm still able to use it for pretty long.

After multiple reboots yesterday, the problem was fixed for once and I was able to see correct battery percentage but the problem came up again today after booting it up from shutdown state. I don't understand the issue and don't seem to find similar issues with M1 chips online. There are some issues with Intel Chip, but they suggest to reset SMC. For M1, it was suggested to restart but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Battery Usage History]

Comment: Hi I have the same macbook and got the same problem. Please help me if you were able to find a solution

Comment: It's a hardware issue. You'll need to get it repaired.

Comment: So the apple store's telling me to replace the keyboard + battery for 
Rs.44800.

Comment: Is this the only option? What else can I do please help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any other option. Mine was an office laptop and they also took it to Apple for repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no reset SMC option for the new Apple silicon Macs. More on this here: https://www.macworld.com/article/669231/how-to-reset-the-smc-on-an-m1-or-intel-mac.html

I'd recommend opening a support ticket with Apple to see if they can diagnose remotely or book you in for a repair.